# Regarding certificate in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate, pfx

We have a web service published at a given URL https://< fakeURL >.com?service.wsdl

In order to make its Java client ,
1)I downloaded its .crt file from Firefox as  Export certificate >> save to file  >> it automatically took .crt extension .

2) I used that .crt file in Java program and set it  in SSLContextFactory and made  HttpsURLConnection and am able to post  data and get results  .

```
InputStream certstream = fullStream ("path to .crt file /ABC.crt");
Certificate certs = cf.generateCertificate(certstream);         

// Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("isakey", certs);

// Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

// Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();

URL                url; 
HttpsURLConnection       urlConn; 
url = new URL("https://path to web service /");             
String rawData = "param1=abc&param2=efg";         
byte[] postData = rawData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);          
urlConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();            
urlConn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
```

As per my understanding above code is reading certificate and wrapping it in each request .
Things were fine  until i was asked by management to share the certificate with other Team who is also a consumer of same Web Service .
Other team uses .NET C# to connect to WS .

After I shared , .NET  team asked me to share private key .

Now I am wondering because

1)   as per  my understanding  they can ask public key ..not the private key . Because  private key is what server owns and is confidential .
2)  While exporting certificate through firefox it  includes  key with it  if in case  public key is attached with it . I saw that option was  not enabled .
So there is  no public key in this certificate .

3)  Other team is saying since their  client is in .NET and it doesn’t accept  .crt file , It only accepts  .pfx file .

> > Can it be possible  ?  are certificate format technology dependent .
> >
> > Even if  they say that  only .pfx file can be accepted  , They should have to use their  own private key to convert  .crt file to .pfx  .
> >     There are commands to convert crt file to pfx  , but i think for this  .NET team has to use their  own private key

Convert a PEM certificate file and a private key to PKCS#12 (.pfx .p12)

openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile CACert.crt

> > where privateKey.key is there private key .

Can some one  help me in understanding  their  case ?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. We got what you have done and what results you have. We still have no clue what is your final goal.

Answer (score 2):

Consumers do not need the private key. If i understand this correctly, your consumer client needs to trust the certificate presented by your web service when making request to your web service. If it is a production scenario, your certificate will be issued by a trusted public CA, which will be trusted by all clients.

If you are using a self signed cert for development scenario, ask the client team to import the cert (only public key) to trusted root.

Also check what kind of error they are receiving while consuming the service.

Comment: Hi Shetty , Thanks for the answer . And thanks for  verifying that i was correct. Now i am feeling a fool of myself because I found just now that Team was  just asking stupid questions to take more time for development activity . This is so sad  . Anyway , i am relaxed . Best Regards